# How to normalise the histogram height in matplotlib

Tags: python, graphs

I am trying to create a histogram plot with `matplotlib`. I am using `bmi` column from four different data frames (d1, d2, d2, d4).

The issue is that these 4 datasets have different sample sizes. So there is a disparity between the heights of the bar.

Is there any additional option in the matplotlib to normalize the heights of the bar?

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bmiplot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/110.0, graphHeight/150.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    d1 = dm_group1
    d2 = dm_group2
    d3 = dm_group3
    d4 = dm_group4

    plt.hist([d1.bmi.values.flatten(), d2.bmi.values.flatten(), d3.bmi.values.flatten(), d4.bmi.values.flatten()], 
    label=['bmi_dm1', 'bmi_dm2', 'bmi_dm3', 'bmi_dm4'])
    plt.legend()
    plt.rc('xtick')
    plt.rc('ytick')
    

graphWidth = 700
graphHeight = 800
bmiplot(graphWidth, graphHeight)

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is `density`, traditionally the code would be ...

```
kwargs = dict(histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.4, normed=True, bins=50)

plt.hist(d1, **kwargs)
plt.hist(d2, **kwargs)
plt.hist(d3, **kwargs);
```

`alpha` is transparency allowing overlapping distributions.

**Note** `normed` is deprecated, the blurb [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) describes `density` now replacing it.

The blurb is here:

> matplotlib.pyplot.hist(x, bins=None, range=None, density=False,
> weights=None, ... **kwargs)

The definition of `density` is here

> densitybool, default: False If True, draw and return a probability
> density: each bin will display the bin's raw count divided by the
> total number of counts and the bin width (density = counts /
> (sum(counts) * np.diff(bins))), so that the area under the histogram
> integrates to 1 (np.sum(density * np.diff(bins)) == 1). If stacked is
> also True, the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.

A different approach is relative frequency, via the `weights` command.

```
 plt.hist(mydata, weights= *)
```

*, relative counts per data type / total counts over all data types